# how to share login data between two android application like Facebook app and facebook messsenger

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-sharing, android-account

i am developing two apps with login functionality like APP1 and APP2 i want login user session which logged in in APP1 like Facebook App and Facebook messenger App.

how can i share my login session of APP1 with APP2?

Comment: its using webservices

Comment: its using intent service as well as session

Answer (score 1):

I can give the below scenario

1)Both apps should have same APPUSERID.

Workflow of APP2 wants to read data from APP1

1)It needs installation information of APP1. (Get the PackageManager)

2)Call ApplicationInfo.getApplicationInfo (Get the META-DATA)

**Steps**

1)Save the content you want to access in APP2 in a file in APP1.

This is in APP1

```
FileOutputStream fos = null
File file = null;
file = getFilesDir();
fos = openFileOutput("my.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String text = "hello";
fos.write(text.getBytes());
```

In APP2

```
String packageName = "your.package.name.of.app1";
```

2)Then load the file saved in APP1

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

String filePath = appInfo.dataDir + "/files/my.txt";
```

3) Then read the file using

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (new File (filePath));
// Please write the further code
```

4)Have the same userID in both APP1 and APP2, i.e. after `packag="x.y.z"` write the below line in both applications `AndroidManifest.xml`

`android:sharedUserID = "a.b.c";`   // Make sure to include this line in both apps manifest file. Here `a.b.c` and `x.y.z` are raw data.

**P.S : I have not handled the exceptions.**

Comment: @NeerajMehta I have modified the answer. Please check

Comment: UPDATE: Scoped storage wont let you do that now.